# Excel 2016 Upgraded From 2007; Any Workarounds for Apparent Memory Issue?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2016

This isn't really a programming question perse, but at work we have been forced to upgrade from Excel 2007 to Excel 2016 which has caused some productivity issues with respect to opening multiple workbooks at once.

The problem is that our entire file system has a bunch of linked formulas and iterative calculations where it is necessary to have multiple workbooks open at once (around 60+). Previously with Excel 2007 we were able to do this easily with relatively low power computers (4 gigs of ram, with a mediocre hyperthreaded i3 processor) but with the new change to Excel 2016 we keep getting an error stating to "upgrade to 64-bit Excel" or "install more physical memory". The error message can be seen [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=excel+2016+error+upgrade+to+64+or+install+more+ram&rls=com.microsoft:en-CA:IE-Address&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEiovS_ZPYAhVK5YMKHcarCsgQ_AUIDSgE&biw=1067&bih=547#imgrc=nvnQJ-juKfyOzM:&spf=1513614569202). We have already upgraded to 64-bit Excel, and on top of that, I tried using other co workers computers with 8 and 16 gigs of ram which resulted in little to no difference. Does this imply that perhaps Excel 2016 is not well optimized for having this many workbooks open at the same time? Are there solutions or workarounds this problem? I find it hard to believe that 16 gigs of ram is still insufficient when 2007 was able to go through this process easily, though perhaps the change from MDI to SDI means less efficiency?

As an aside, yes, I do indeed wish we were not using Excel for such a computationally expensive process in which Excel may not have been designed for tasks like these, but to move everything to something like SAS would take a lot of time I'd imagine and ultimately, I don't make the decisions :(

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What build of Excel 2016 are you using? More recent builds have some memory optimisations which might help. See https://office-watch.com/2017/excel-performance-improvements/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-performance-and-limit-improvements for relevant build numbers

Comment: Looks like we are using Excel 16.0.4549.1000.

I'll take a look into this, thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to tell what the latest build is, or what date my build corresponds to? I've googled but nothing has really come up.

Comment: The original MSI build was 16.0.4266.1000 so does not look like you have any significant updates. See https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Changes-to-Slow-Fast-level-names-for-Office-Insider-for-Windows-desktop-055ee4f9-9ce3-4fb8-8a9a-ca6745867d52 fore some details of the updating options.

Comment: There is some information about build numbers and dates here https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Version-and-build-numbers-of-update-channel-releases-ae942449-1fca-4484-898b-a933ea23def7#bkmk_bydate